# Is Google Ad Manager tracking users that didn't consented to be tracked?

Tags: analytics, google-analytics-4, google-ad-manager

I'm supporting a friend who is using Google Ad Manager to serve ads to people that view the website. I know that Ads can get served to all users, but we aren't allowed to track users that don't consent to tracking. Are their Ad views registered in GAM? What should I look for to know specifically. We are hoping to use the new reporting type Analytics. I'm interested in the 30-day active users metric. Does this number include data for unconsented users?

I've looked at the 30-day active user number, but it isn't detailed enough for us to determine if it is accurate or now. The [official documentation](https://support.google.com/admanager/table/7568664?sjid=15746673513693828326-EU) isn't sufficiently detailed for me to answer the question. The 30-day report type was added in the last 6 months.